# Sum of a column within the subquery in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sum, subquery

I have a Postgresql table where I have 2 fields i.e. ID and Name ie column1 and column2 in the SQLFiddle. The default record_count I put for a particular ID is 1. I want to get the record_count for column 1 and sum that record_count by column1.
I tried to use this query but somehow its showing some error.

```
select sum(column_record)  group by column_record ,
* from (select column1,1::int4 as column_record from test) a
```

Also find the Input/Output screenshot in the form of excel below :

[image]

SQL Fiddle for the same :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12fe9/1

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a window function (you may want to use normal grouping, which is "a lot" more faster and performant), this is the way to do it:

```
-- create temp table test as (select * from (values ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')) a(column1, column2));
select sum(column_record) over (partition by column_record),
* from (select column1, 1::int4 as column_record from test) a;
```